# Solution of the equation $(x^2-x-1)^{x+2}=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the equation $$(x^2-x-1)^{x+2}=1$$  in $\mathbb{Z}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either $x^2-x-1 = 1$, $x+2 = 0$, or $x^2-x-1 = -1$ and $x+2$ is even.

Comment: More precisely, $x^2-x-1\in\{\pm 1\}.$

Comment: Start by taking logs on both sides. See if you get to the claims made in the other comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow baudolino's suggestion, we take log on both sides of the original equation:

$$(x+2)\ln(x^2-x-1)=0......(1)$$
$$\ln(-x^2+x+1)=0, x+2 = 2k (k=1,2,3...)......(2)$$

Thus

$$x+2=0 \implies x_1=-2$$

$$\ln(x^2-x-1)=0 \implies x^2-x-1=1 \implies x_2=-1, \text{or}, x_3=2$$

$$\ln(-x^2+x+1)=0 \text{ and } x+2=2k \implies x_4=0$$

We can verify these four roots by plug them into the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

An integer power of an integer ($a^b$) can only be $1$ in the following cases:

1. $b = 0$ (with the case $a=0$ debatable)
2. $a = 1$
3. $a = -1$, $b$ even.